# NPM - cant install Packeges

Tags: npm, npm-install

Terminal input:
`npm init -y` working as expected,
`npm install --save cors nodedom express socket.io`

getting this eror:

```
npm ERR! 404 Object Not Found - GET https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/nodedom - not_found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'nodedom@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Guy Arieli\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-14T17_02_20_885Z-debug.log
PS C:\Code\React\Chattime\server> npm config set registry https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Object Not Found - GET https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/nodedom - not_found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'nodedom@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Guy Arieli\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-14T17_03_26_067Z-debug.log
+ create-react-app@4.0.1
updated 1 package in 163.864s
```

where is the package.jason :

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

When I clone a project with this packets all work well however when I try to install via terminal things don't work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, a package called nodedom is not available on npm.

Did you mean either: [node-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-dom)

or did you mean [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)

Comment: You are right, I thought you install via nodedom and not node-dom,
node-dom works